# Unable to find design file in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

**I wanna make a navigation between views in vaadin. 
I made 2 views with html and navigator but when I initialize the first view I have a DesignException**

```
com.vaadin.ui.declarative.DesignException: Unable to find design file MainView.html in com.andrei
at com.vaadin.ui.declarative.Design.read(Design.java:608)
at com.andrei.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:23)
at com.andrei.MyUI.init(MyUI.java:39)
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:770)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:218)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:76)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

Im tried to put html file in com.andrei directory but it not works , after that 
I found infomation that html file must be in resource folder , but it dont work, again,where I must put this file , or how can I change rootPath to directory

[image]

This is my UI

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {
    Navigator navigator;
    protected static final String MAINVIEW = "main";

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        navigator = new Navigator(this, this);

        // Create and register the views
        navigator.addView("", new StartView());
        navigator.addView(MAINVIEW, new MainView(navigator));



    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

}
```

**This is MainView:**

MainView

```
@DesignRoot
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout implements View {
// Menu navigation button listener


VerticalLayout menuContent;
Panel equalPanel;
Button logout;

public MainView(Navigator navigator) {
    Design.read(this);

    logout.addClickListener(event ->
            navigator.navigateTo(""));
}

@DesignRoot
class AnimalViewer extends VerticalLayout {
    Label watching;
    Embedded pic;
    Label back;

    public AnimalViewer(String animal) {
        Design.read(this);

        watching.setValue("You are currently watching a " +
                animal);
        pic.setSource(new ThemeResource(
                "img/" + animal + "-128px.png"));
        back.setValue("and " + animal +
                " is watching you back");
    }
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
    if (event.getParameters() == null
            || event.getParameters().isEmpty()) {
        equalPanel.setContent(
                new Label("Nothing to see here, " +
                        "just pass along."));
        return;
    } else
        equalPanel.setContent(new AnimalViewer(
                event.getParameters()));
}
}
```

Comment: `find design file MainView.html in com.andrei`.  Put the `MainView.html` in `com/andrei` within your classpath (e.g. inside your resources dir)

Comment: Im sorry but i do not understand, can you explain , I must put  MainView.html in com/andrei , i put it , but nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right location is most likely `/src/main/resources/com/andrei/MainView.html`.